# Pass data to previous tableviewcell in swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I have created 3 outlets for labels,2 actions for buttons and 1 outlet for UIDatePickerView. lblField displays the current date with month, date and year. lblField2 displays the selected dates by the user after pressing dueDate action. lblField3 displays the differences between the current date and selected date.

When I click on the cell of Due date: it opens DatePickerViewController as given above.

Now I need to pass data of lblField3 of DatePickerViewController to "Due date: " cell of TodayViewController in Swift 3 after pressing Done button. How shall I do it using simple way in Swift 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to simply use `delegate/protocol`. Create one delegate and create its instance in the `DatePickerViewController`, Now implement that `protocol` with your `TodayViewController` and when you move to the `DatePickerViewController` set its delegate to the `self`. Now simply call the delegate method on `DatePickerViewController` to pass the data.

```
protocol DatePickerDelegate {
    func getDifference(diff: String) 
}
```

Now create its instance in `DatePickerViewController` and call the method where you get the difference of date.

```
class DatePickerViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: DatePickerDelegate?
    //Other instances property declaration ...

    //other methods

    @IBAction func Done(_ sender: Any) {
        self.delegate?.getDifference(diff: lblField3.text ?? "")
        _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Now simply implement `DatePickerDelegate` with your `TodayViewController` and add its method.

```
class TodayViewController: UIViewController, DatePickerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

     //Other methods

     //Set the delegate when you are push to DatePickerViewController
      let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DatePickerViewController") as! DatePickerViewController        
      //Set delegate of DatePickerViewController 
      secondViewController.delegate = self
      selectedIndexPath = indexPath 

      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)


     //DatePickerDelegate method
     func getDifference(diff: String)  {
         //Access diff here
         print(diff)
     }
}
```

**Edit:** The problem is in `didSelectRowAt` you are comparing the text of cell's label instead of that you need to compare the row of `tableView`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     if (tableView.tag == 1) {
          if indexPath.row == 4 {
               //Show view for Baby size guide:
               let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BabySizeViewController") as! BabySizeViewController
               selectedIndexPath = indexPath
               self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
          }
          else if indexPath.row == 1 {
               //Show view for Due date:
               let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DatePickerViewController") as! DatePickerViewController
               selectedIndexPath = indexPath
               secondViewController.delegate = self
               self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: I tried by declaring global variable. Please help me out there Sir. I have given all codes up there?? U can write codes... I would be happy..

Comment: @Tamannah Check my edited answer, do like that it will work in a way you want.

Comment: Sir, It didn't work out... It doesnt display differences in cell. @ Nirav D

Comment: @Tamannah Your code is look Ok, have you press done button after you set dueDate in `DatePickerViewController`?

Comment: Yes... I did but to doesnt display anything. @ Nirav D

Comment: @Tamannah You have added `print(diff)`, so i'm sure there is difference printing in your console check that once.

Comment: Yes,, It is printed in console. @ Nirav D

Comment: @Tamannah Then simply you need to use that `diff` var to display in place you want.

Comment: yes only that much. Then, how can u pass diff in that cell ? @ Nirav D

Comment: Change `contents1` array to var instead of let and in the delegate method Change the `contents1[1] = diff` and reload the `tableView`.

Comment: @Tamannah Check edit of your question for method `getDifference`.

Comment: No sir. It didn't work out. Can u give me email id so that i can send you screenshots of views  @ Nirav D

Comment: @Tamannah Cureently i'm out of my Mac will help you tomorrow.

Comment: @Tamannah Can you please tell me what is not working, have you set the array object like i have edit your question and then reload the tableView.

Comment: @Tamannah Simply check latest edit of my answer and make your didSelect that way.

Comment: Now... it doesnt show the difference in that label. It became as like before as it shows nothing. @  Nirav D

Comment: I wrote up all the codes with update... u can check there... @ Nirav D

Comment: @Tamannah reload the `tableView` after this line `contents1[1] =  diff` in `getDifference` method i'm sure it will works for you now.

Comment: No.. I is not working still. Now, it doesnt even print diff in console. @ Nirav D

Comment: @Tamannah Forgot to set delegate in `didSelectRowAt` using `secondViewController.delegate = self` add this line like I have added now and will work

Comment: Ohh... Great. Thank u sir !! @ Nirav D